# Regex for first eight letters and last number

Tags: regex, numbers, letter

Please help me compose a working regular expression.
Conditions:

1. There can be a maximum of `9` characters (from 1 to 9).
2. The **first eight characters** can only be **uppercase** letters.
3. The **last** character can only be a **digit**.

Examples:

Do not match:

- `S3`
- `FT5`
- `FGTU7`
- `ERTYUOP9`
- `ERTGHYUKM`

Correspond to:

- `E`
- `ERT`
- `RTYUKL`
- `VBNDEFRW3`

I tried using the following:

```
^[A-Z]{1,8}\d{0,1}$
```

but in this case, the FT5 example matches, although it shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use an alternation based regex:

```sh
^(?:[A-Z]{1,8}|[A-Z]{8}\d)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0J66EM/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `[A-Z]{1,8}`: Match 1 to 8 uppercase letters
  - `|`: OR
  - `[A-Z]{8}\d`: Match 8 uppercase letters followed by a digit
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `$`: End

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You might also rule out the first 7 uppercase chars followed by a digit using a negative lookhead:

```
^(?![A-Z]{1,7}\d)[A-Z]{1,8}\d?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?![A-Z]{1,7}\d)` Negative lookahead to assert not 1-7 uppercase chars and a digit
- `[A-Z]{1,8}` Match 1-8 times an uppercase char
- `\d?` Match an optional digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9S0NoE/1)

Answer (score 1):

With a regex engine that supports possessive quantifiers, you can write:

```
^[A-Z]{1,7}+(?:[A-Z]\d?)?$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/IX0cZv/1)

The letter in the optional group can only succeed when the quantifier in `[A-Z]{1,7}+` reaches the maximum and when a letter remains. The letter in the group can only be the 8th character.

For the .net regex engine (that doesn't support possessive quantifiers) you can write this pattern using an atomic group:

```
^(?>[A-Z]{1,7})(?:[A-Z]\d?)?$
```